# Was this question migrated in error?

Tags: support, migration, specific-question

I think [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/15928/16837) has been migrated to Code Review incorrectly: although there is a lot of code in the question, it repeats in a pattern that can be solved with a single straightforward trick. In fact, had the code snippet not be repeated five times, it is unlikely that anyone would even consider migrating the question to the Code Review. site.

Could you please migrate the question back to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I migrated this question because it's not about solving a specific problem. The OP has already done that, the code works for him except it's not pretty.

Instead he's asking about how to refactor (*clean*) his code which in this case means some or all of:

- make it less verbose
- make it more readable
- remove redundant/duplicate ops

..and that's a code review thing.

Code reviewing is also about more experienced developers introducing less experienced developers (generally, or in a specific language) to more advanced language features or language idiomatic ways of doing things.

So I'm happy that migrating was the right thing to do. If this had remained on SO it would have been closed as Not Constructive.

Comment: .... and likely eventually deleted.

Comment: I'm curious if the question had any closing votes before you migrated it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - It was flagged for migration. Also as Tim rightly pointed out, if the question was closed then it's at risk of deletion by the community.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight [It had four close votes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589640/how-can-i-make-this-cleaner?noredirect=1)

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah, nice link! Thanks! Is there a way to get a link to see the question before the migration without playing around with the URL?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You'll have to have the ?noredirect on it, but it's linked from the destination site where the notice says "migrated from". That's a link back to the original. (And "migrated to" on the original version links back to the new location.)

Comment: ..ah yes, sorry 4 close votes - silly me - and a flag.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a valid migration to me, since the code is working and the asker was looking for suggestions on cleaning it up/improving it aesthetically rather than fixing a bug of some sort.

> although there is a lot of code in the question, it repeats in a pattern that can be solved with a single straightforward trick. In fact, had the code snippet not be repeated five times, it is unlikely that anyone would even consider migrating the question to the Code Review. site.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. There's no complexity requirement on Code Review, nor is there a requirement to keep simple questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although there is no minimal complexity requirement for code on CR, a question related to a language construct, rather than a more or less complete snippet of code, would probably be kept on SO. This question is about replacing an `if` with a one-line construct (a `?` or a `??`), a trick applicable far beyond the snippet provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you said:

> nifty ways out there to clean this up, I'm just not sure what they
>   are. I'm not familiar enough with c# to know of the best ways. Anyone
>   out there better than me and can help

It makes it sound like more of a code-review Question. The `clean this up` is the real marker.

If you modify it to be specific, perhaps it would fly on SO proper.